# Can I run 2 separate projects on xCode workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Is there an equivalent to [Gradle Composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) for xCode?
I want to run 2 separate projects, my app and a pod project, which is not connected statically, only trough pod.
Is it posible?

Comment: it was a mistake, I've fixed it ;-)

Comment: I know it's not possible to run 2 different projects, But there must be a solution for Pods project developers, I'll wait to see if someone have an idea

Comment: That's right, other people will also have some suggestions about it.

Answer (score 0):

No It is not possible. You cannot run 2 separate projects.